# Estimating the Growth Rate of Worms

Tags: estimation

I would like to know how much worms I'd have on hand given an initial amount and period of time. Here are some metrics regarding the growth rate of these worms.

```
2.45 - 3.5 cocoons per adult worm per day.
2.5 - 3.8 worms per cocoon
Incubation period 18 - 26 days
Hatchling viability 73% - 80%
30 days from hatchling to adult
Earthworm Life Expectance is 594 days (assume from hatchling).
```

How can I calculate the estimated amount of worms I'd have if I started with `N` amount of worms, after `t` amount of time?

Comment: What is meant by $2.45 - 3.5$ cocoons per adult worm per day? If this gives just the range of this number, that is not enough information.

Comment: @user133281, it does give the range of this number, which implies that there will be a min and a max.

Comment: Then you don't have sufficient information to estimate $N$.

Comment: Can't you estimate a range?

Answer (score 0):

Hint - try using the data available to you to determine the multiplied increase in a population as a result of ONE worm in a given time period.

Comment: I've tried that, because regardless of what unit you use (be it one worm, one kilogram of worms), the growth rate will remain the same.